# How to analyze the source of TCP Retransmissions

Tags: windows-7, networking, firefox, tcp, wireshark

I am requesting a URL (so the following happens with a HTTP GET request) from Firefox 50.0.2 and I'm using the auto refresh feature with a 1 second timeout. I'm observing TCP retransmissions like this:

```
Frame 429: 448 bytes on wire (3584 bits), 448 bytes captured (3584 bits) on interface 0
    Interface id: 0 (\Device\NPF_{F19F8E72-77DA-478F-A55F-4F609F5B150C})
    Encapsulation type: Ethernet (1)
    Arrival Time: Dec 12, 2016 15:51:28.811504000 W. Europe Standard Time
    [...]
Ethernet II, [...]
Internet Protocol Version 4
[...]
Identification: 0x3f39 (16185)
[...]
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 16081 (16081), Dst Port: vcom-tunnel (8001), Seq: 10245, Ack: 35123, Len: 394
    [...]
    Sequence number: 10245    (relative sequence number)
    [...]
```

and immediately following

```
Frame 430: 448 bytes on wire (3584 bits), 448 bytes captured (3584 bits) on interface 0
    Interface id: 0 (\Device\NPF_{F19F8E72-77DA-478F-A55F-4F609F5B150C})
    Encapsulation type: Ethernet (1)
    Arrival Time: Dec 12, 2016 15:51:28.811506000 W. Europe Standard Time
    [...]
Ethernet II, [...]
Internet Protocol Version 4
[...]
Identification: 0x3f39 (16185)
[...]
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 16081 (16081), Dst Port: vcom-tunnel (8001), Seq: 10245, Ack: 35123, Len: 394
    [...]
    Sequence number: 10245    (relative sequence number)
    [...]
    [SEQ/ACK analysis]
        [iRTT: 0.000387000 seconds]
        [Bytes in flight: 394]
        [Bytes sent since last PSH flag: 394]
        [TCP Analysis Flags]
            [Expert Info (Note/Sequence): This frame is a (suspected) retransmission]
                [This frame is a (suspected) retransmission]
                [Severity level: Note]
                [Group: Sequence]
            [The RTO for this segment was: 0.000002000 seconds]
            [RTO based on delta from frame: 429]
    Retransmitted TCP segment data (394 bytes)
```

As you can see:

- the two frames have the same sequence number
- the frame number increases just by 1
- the time increases by 2 microseconds (.811504000 / .811506000)
- Wireshark detects the second packet as TCP retransmission

How do I find out the source of this retransmission? Is it

- a bug in Wireshark? (Version 2.2.2 (v2.2.2-0-g775fb08))
- a bug in the WinPCap driver? (Version 4.1.3)
- a bug in Firefox? (Version 50.0.2)

Additional information:

- I see these lines with a distance of 1 second, so there's always a green line (HTTP) and a black line (TCP retransmission) or a grey line (TCP) and a black line (TCP Dup ACK)
- I'm on Windows 7 SP1 x64.
- I'm using a Wiresharp capture filter for the TCP port I'm interested in
- I'm using a Wireshark display filter for HTTP
- I'm monitoring traffic on an external USB Ethernet interface which does not have an IP address.
- That adapter is connected to a mirroring port of my HP 1820-8G switch. It's configured to be one-way, i.e. I can receive packets only.
- My wireless connection as well as any other connections (Bluetooth, VMWare) are disabled (adapter disabled), only my LAN adapter and the USB adapter are enabled, of course

Here's my Setup:

[image: Wireshark Setup]

I have tried:

- powering off and on the HP 1820-8G switch
- uninstalling WinPCap
- upgrading to Wireshark 2.2.3 and reinstalling WinPCap 4.1.3 that comes with Wireshark

Comment: Do both frames have the same IPID? How many of these are you seeing per second? Is Wi-Fi involved in this packet trace? Are you running Wireshark on the same machine as Firefox?

Comment: @Spiff: I updated the question

Comment: Because the re-transmissions are occurring extremely quickly (before RTO has expired), it's likely that you are seeing duplicate packets rather than real re-transmissions. You can check by inspecting the IP `Identification` field on two of the packets to see if the ID changes between the original packet and re-transmitted one.  Duplicate packets will have the same ID, re-transmitted packets will have a unique ID.

Comment: @MarkoPolo: yes, you're right, the Identification field in the IP header is identical. I added this to the question.

Comment: Can you take a capture at any other point in the transmission path to see if the duplicate packets are actually being sent on the wire? If not, then it is a local Wireshark/capture issue.